# Django admin foreign key field filtering

Tags: django, widget, django-admin

I have client model which has a foreign key field to a country model.

So in Django admin, when I create a client and I select the country where this client belongs to. but the problem is the select list is too long(too many countries on this planet). Sometimes it takes just too long to get the one I need.

So I wonder if there is other widget in djano admin that provides a select-input-combo widget.
When I type in the input and it will filter out the right one for me to select.

Hope you can understand what I need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Django 2.0 there is `autocomplete_fields`. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields):

> autocomplete_fields is a list of ForeignKey and/or ManyToManyField fields you would like to change to Select2 autocomplete inputs.

and

> The Select2 input looks similar to the default input but comes with a search feature that loads the options asynchronously. This is faster and more user-friendly if the related model has many instances.

Note that you need to define `search_fields` in the related object's ModelAdmin since it is used by the widget.

Answer (score 5):

did you see [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) ?

you would do in admin.py something like:

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("country",)
admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

then select widget will become something like:

[image]

Comment: It's kinda ok, but not the perfect widget, I guess i'll have to make own. Do you know how to display other filed value instead of just plain id number?

Comment: @castiel do you have _\_unicode_\_  in your foreign models?

Comment: Note: the "magnifier" link pops up a selection window with filter box.